# Non-breaking \hspace in ConTeXt

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, context

The only non-breakable space command in ConTeXt that I know of is the tilde (~) command, but I'd like to have finer control over how long the non-breaking space will be. In LaTeX, I could accomplish this with \hspace*, but ConTeXt only offers the non-starred version of the command, and this produces a breakable space.

Does ConTeXt offer a non-breaking version of its \hspace command, or is there another preferred way of doing this in ConTeXt? I'd be content with temporarily modifying the width of the ~ space, but I'm also not sure how I might do that.

Comment: Are you familiar with `\kern1cm`, `\kern5em`, etc?

Comment: I was not, so thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\kern` as Mico suggested in a comment, however, that has the disadvantage, that it doesn't stretch or shrink.

To get a horizontal space that can't be broken around and that stretches and shrinks like interword space, you can use

```
\nobreak\hskip1em plus 1em minus .5em\nobreak
```

However, that also doesn't fit well with the ConTeXt philosophy of first class Unicode support.  Instead of specifying space manually, maybe have a look at all the predefined horizontal spaces in [`spac-chr.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/9a1b9756939e12e328dea3633d9fe3cbde8f154b/tex/context/base/mkiv/spac-chr.mkiv), which are natively supported by ConTeXt.  The big advantage of those is that they properly export to XML and are copy-pastable from PDF.  If they are breakable, it should be possible to just surround them with `\nobreak` like above.

Here is a shortened excerpt from [`spac-chr.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/9a1b9756939e12e328dea3633d9fe3cbde8f154b/tex/context/base/mkiv/spac-chr.mkiv):

```
\edef\nobreakspace            {\normalUchar"00A0} % space
\edef\softhyphen              {\normalUchar"00AD} % softhyohen
\edef\enquad                  {\normalUchar"2000} % quad/2
\edef\emquad                  {\normalUchar"2001} % quad

\let\ideographicspace         \enquad
\let\ideographichalffillspace \emquad

\edef\twoperemspace           {\normalUchar"2002} % quad/2
\edef\threeperemspace         {\normalUchar"2004} % quad/3
\edef\fourperemspace          {\normalUchar"2005} % quad/4
\edef\sixperemspace           {\normalUchar"2006} % quad/6
\edef\figurespace             {\normalUchar"2007} % width of zero
\edef\punctuationspace        {\normalUchar"2008} % width of period
\edef\breakablethinspace      {\normalUchar"2009} % quad/8
\edef\hairspace               {\normalUchar"200A} % quad/8
\edef\zerowidthspace          {\normalUchar"200B} % 0
\edef\zerowidthnonjoiner      {\normalUchar"200C} % 0
\edef\zerowidthjoiner         {\normalUchar"200D} % 0
\edef\narrownobreakspace      {\normalUchar"202F} % quad/8

\udef\zerowidthnobreakspace   {\penalty\plustenthousand\kern\zeropoint}
\udef\fiveperemspace          {\hskip\dimexpr\emwidth/5\relax}
```

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer! It looks like \nobreak was the command I needed. I originally would've used something like \nobreak\hspace[medium] (and this works when I test it), but \nobreak\enquad creates a non-breaking space of the same width, and it does so with all the Unicode-related advantages you outlined above!